# Is there a way to change someDataGridViewCell.Style.BackColor (&etc) at any time?

Tags: winforms

Documentation says it must be done inside someDataGridView.CellFormatting event, but how can you pass the needed color information into it and force CellFormatting to be triggered when needed ?

someDataGridViewCell.Value is working fine for changing cell text from a System.Windows.Forms.Timer Tick event, but I can't seem to change the coloring at the same time.
In my case, all the columns are built and changed dynamically from user menus, and there can be dozens of them.

This is VS2015.

Update:
My issue was I used Color.FromName() which returns Empty (transparent) for misspelled names -- very very bad for grid background colors. (I required coloring in data streams I was using so name seemed handy.)

CellFormatting event used in most examples assumes you can derive the color information from the visible cell contents which is too limiting.

Comment: The `CellFormatting` event is raised much more frequently that you image (until you test it). E.g., each time you change a value. Or select a Cell. You can build a procedure (a method), that can return a Color based on the current Cell value. It's up to you to define which Color to apply to whatever Cell value you have.

Comment: _”Documentation says it must be done inside someDataGridView.CellFormatting event”_ … It is unclear “where” you are getting this documentation, however it is wrong as is your assumption. You can change a grids cell color whenever you want and you don’t have to call any of the grid's event to do this. Your information/assumption is just wrong. You should provide a [mre] that demonstrates what the problem is.

Comment: Color.FromName()  was issue. Now it works as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `CellFormatting` event is recommended if you are changing colors on the datagridview on the `Load` event of the Form. Once the form has been `Shown` you can modify the cells in any method.

How you would do it would depend on how you iterate through the view and what you're trying to accomplish. Since you didn't specify VB or C# I'll put both.

Single Cell:

```
VB:
dgv.Rows(index).Cells(index).Style.BackColor = Color.PickAColor

C#:
dgv.Rows[index].Cells[index].Style.BackColor = Color.PickAColor;
```

Entire Row:

```
VB:
dgv.Rows(index).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.PickAColor

C#:
dgv.Rows[index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.PickAColor;
```

Entire row while through the rows:

```
VB:
For Each row As DataGridViewRow in dgv.Rows
    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.PickAColor
Next

C#:
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
{
    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.PickAColor;
}
```

Essentially if you're styling a single cell use the `Cell.Style.BackColor` and if you want to do the entire row then use the `Row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor`

Comment: It works as expected. Thanks.
My issue was with Color.FromName producing transparent backgrounds.